# Prove that $a^6-a^5+a^4-a^3+1>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

Prove that $a^6-a^5+a^4-a^3+1>0$.

What I tried and why this question is very tricky:
I tired to decompose all the $a$ and find a common "denominator", I tried multiple methods, some with radicals another with multiplying with numbers to have a common base, I also tried this: $a^6-a^5+a^4-a^3>0-1=-1$ and multiply both sides by $-1$ to have a positive number ($1$) and to change the symbol ($>$ becomes $<$) My ideas didn't work, maybe they were incorrect or I didn't solve them correct. Tell me what do you think.

Comment: I also tried to factor the entire expression!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).m/q/1773).

Comment: FWIW, the minimum value of the expression occurs when $a = \frac{1}{18} \left( 5 - \frac{47}{\sqrt[3]{1043 + 18 \sqrt{3678}}} + \sqrt[3]{1043 + 18 \sqrt{3678}} \right) \approx 0.7903088603839408$, giving $f(a) \approx 0.8318434071389804$.  I'm not posting that as an answer because it's very difficult to find without computer assistance.

Comment: @Dan,thanks for your response!

Answer (score 10):

Let $\displaystyle f(a)=a^6-a^5+a^4-a^3+1$

$\bullet $ For $a\leq 0,$ Then $f(a)>0$

$\bullet $ For $0<a<1,$ Then $f(a)=a^6+a^4(1-a)+(1-a^3)>0$

$\bullet $ For $a\geq 1,$ Then $f(a)=a^5(a-1)+a^3(a-1)+1>0$

So we have $f(a)>0$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do you know the second claim is true?

Comment: In $a\in(0,1),$ We have $(1-a),(1-a^3)>0$

Answer (score 2):

A general method that only works with *Discriminants* :

---

Let's transform the given polynomial into the *quadratic-like* polynomial with respect to $\color{#c00}{a^2}$ :

$$
\begin{align}P(a):&=a^6-a^5+a^4-a^3+1\\
&=\small{\underbrace{(a^2-a+1)}_{>\thinspace 0,\thinspace \forall a\thinspace\in\thinspace\mathbb R}\color{#c00}{\left(a^2\right)^2}-a\cdot \color{#c00}{a^2}+1}
\end{align}
$$

Then, we determine the Discriminant $\Delta_{\color{#c00}{a^2}}$ :

$$
\begin{align}\Delta_{\color{#c00}{a^2}}&=a^2-4(a^2-a+1)\\
&=-\underbrace{\left(3\color{#0a0}{a^2}-4\color{#0a0}{a}+4\right)}_{\Delta_{\color{#0a0}{a}}=\thinspace-8\thinspace <\thinspace 0}\\
&<0,\thinspace \forall a\in\mathbb R\thinspace . \end{align}
$$

Since $\Delta_{\color{#c00}{a^2}}<0$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$, this means that $P(a)>0,\thinspace \forall a\in\mathbb R$ which completes the proof .

Comment: Nice way Lone student.

Comment: Can you please tell me How can I solve it above way....https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274331/show-that-x12-x9x4-x1-geq0-for-all-x

Comment: @jacky If I see a way with the same method, I will leave you a comment/solution .

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

$f(a)=a^6-a^5+a^4-a^3+1$

$\displaystyle 2f(a)=2a^6-2a^5+2a^4-2a^3+2$

$\displaystyle 2f(a)=a^6+(a^6-2a^3\cdot a^2+a^4)+(a^4-2a^2\cdot a+a^2)+(a^4-a^2+\frac{1}{4})+\frac{3}{4} $

$\displaystyle 2f(a)=a^6+(a^3-a^2)^2+(a^2-a)^2+(a^2-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}>0$

So we have $2f(a)>0\Longrightarrow f(a)>0 \;\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Completing the square seems incorrect : $$\small {2f(a)=2 a^6 - 2 a^5 + 3 a^4 - 2 a^3 + 1}$$

Comment: @jacky Thanks for the help!!!!